# Authentication et logout using Keycloak in React js app

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

I would like to authenticate my React js application while using the keycloak login page and be able to log out to my application.

I will like to display keycloak login page first and after user authentication it is directed to my react js application and on the application I would like to create a logout button which will redirect the user to the page connection.

Answer (score 0):

You probably would like to have a look at the documentation - I think the javascript adapter might be what you are looking for:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_javascript_adapter